# float to embedded c float over UART

Tags: python, c, struct, floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to send python float's over UART to an Embedded c processor, the MKE14 from NXP. In python I am using the Struct library to make a 32 bit float and send this over UART. I checked both float impelementations and there both "IEEE-754".

I send Decimal: 5.490715       Hex: 0x40, 0xAF, 0xB3, 0xF0

I receive in "Longitude"      Decimal: 1085256688 Hex: 0x40, 0xAF, 0xB3, 0xF0

After float conv              Decimal: 1085256704 Hex: 0x40, 0xAF, 0xB4, 0x00

It must be some conversion problem, I receive the right packet but the representation is tottaly different.

The used code on both systems are in the attached file.

[Python code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftt5T.png)

[Embedded C code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIEG5.png)

Comment: No screenshot of text please. Just copy paste it!

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: First suggestion : take a couple of reference numbers (2.0 ; 3.14159 ; 1000000) and check their HEX representation on both sides. I mean : independantly of the transmission line. In many cases, there is a simple problem of endiannes and all you have to do is to revert the bytes (or the bits) order.

Comment: Yeah, most likely an endian issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert an integer bitpattern to a `float` by means of a cast. That just converts the integer to the nearest floating-point number, it does *not* re-interpret the bits as being a `float`. If it worked like you think, this:

```
const float x = 512;
```

would set `x` to `7.175E-43`, which would not be very convenient.

The best way is probably to just copy the bits, so replace

```
SUS_Data.Longitude = ((float)Longitude);
```

by:

```
memcpy(&SUS_Data.Longitude, &Longitude, sizeof SUS_Data.Longitude);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the pointer and typecast to a float pointer:

```
uint32 tmp = 1085256688;
float f;

f = *((float *) &tmp); // 5.490715
```

or use a union:

```
union test {
  uint32_t u;
  float f;
};
union test tmp;
tmp.u = 1085256688; // tmp.f == 5.490715
```

in your case:

```
SUS_Data.Longitude = *((float *) &Longitude);
```